# Iterate through Vec data and modify a field

Tags: iter, vec

I have the following code. Its a loop of an account's stored Vec that have an address and a number on it structure. Inside the loop, if a vec's address is the payer addres, then I want to substract 1 from the number field of that address.

```
#[account]
#[derive(Default)]
pub struct AccountPda{
    pub data: Vec<Structure>,
    pub bump: u8,
}

#[account]
#[derive(Default)]
pub struct Structure{
    pub address: Pubkey,
    pub number: u8,
}

#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct Ctx<'info> {
    ...
    /// CHECK: Just testing
    #[account(mut)]
    pub payer: Signer<'info>,
    #[account(mut, seeds = [b"seeds".as_ref()], bump = account_pda.bump)]
    account_pda: Account<'info, AccountPda>,
    ...
}

pub fn iter_account(ctx: Context<Ctx>) -> Result<()> {

        for x in ctx.accounts.account_pda.data.iter() {
            if x.address == ctx.accounts.payer.key() {
                x.number -= 1;
                break;
            }
        }
 Ok(())
}
```

Im getting the following error:
cannot assign to `x.number`, which is behind a `&` reference
`x` is a `&` reference, so the data it refers to cannot be writtenrustc(E0594)

Any idea on how to do this?
Thanks.

Comment: does `iter_mut()` fix the problem ?

Comment: This is a rust question, not a Solana question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to do a mutable iterate through the Vec since you are modifying its values.

use `iter_mut()`

```
for x in ctx.accounts.account_pda.data.iter_mut() { .. }
```

**or**

```
for x in &mut ctx.accounts.account_pda.data { .. }
```